# write dependency rule in makefile for project that use AM_LDFLAGS

Tags: c, makefile, dependencies, autotools

I want to write the dependency rule for my project as the project contains src directory and the src folder contains main.c that depend on file1.c and file1.c depend on file2.c 
and I have non standard libraries directory and non standard include directory 
I use AM_CFLAGS = /path to include directory and AM_LDFLAGS = path to lib directory 
I want to make generic dependency rule 
I've tried to play with

```
depend:
     makedepend $(AM_CFLAGS) $(SRC_DIR)
```

but it complained about the libraries that it uses, so I want to make generic dependency rule in order to not rewrite the rule when any one adds new file or change something in the files

here is the makefile of the src directory:

```
   program_NAME := SRR

    AM_CPPFLAGS = \
       -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""$(localedir)"\" \
       -DPACKAGE_SRC_DIR=\""$(srcdir)"\" \
       -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""$(pkgdatadir)"\"


  bin_PROGRAMS = SRR_AutoProject

  program_INCLUDE_DIRS := /usr/bin/SRR__bin

  program_LIBRARY_DIRS := /usr/lib/SRR__lib

  AM_CFLAGS = 

  AM_CFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(program_INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))

  program_lib2 := \
         SRR___wrapper_library__ml \
         srrynarray \
         prhash \
         prhash_pic \
         prhistogram \
         prlistofarrays \
         vreo_wrapper_library 
 AM_LDFLAGS = 

 AM_LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir))

 AM_LDFLAGS += $(foreach library,$(program_lib2),-l$(library))

 SRR_AutoProject_SOURCES = \
         main.c \
         file1.c \
         file2.c

  depend: 
     makedepend $(AM_CFLAGS) $(SRR_AutoProject_SOURCES)
```

the makefile of the root directory as shown below:

```
    SUBDIRS = src

    SRR_AutoProjectdocdir = ${prefix}/doc/PRDSL_AutoProject
    SRR_AutoProjectdoc_DATA = \
          README\
          COPYING\
          AUTHORS\
          ChangeLog\
          INSTALL\
          NEWS


    INTLTOOL_FILES = intltool-extract.in \
           intltool-merge.in \
           intltool-update.in

    EXTRA_DIST = $(PRDSL_AutoProjectdoc_DATA) \
           $(INTLTOOL_FILES)

      DISTCLEANFILES = intltool-extract \
           intltool-merge \
           intltool-update \
           po/.intltool-merge-cache


     # Remove doc directory on uninstall
      uninstall-local:
           -rm -r $(PRDSL_AutoProjectdocdir)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
here is a makedepend rule, extracted from:
<http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html>

INCLUDES := -I/home/newhall/include  -I../include
SRCS := $(wildcard:*.c)

.PHONY: depend

depend: $(SRCS)
    makedepend $(INCLUDES) $^

# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- make depend needs it
```

Comment: Thank you but what about LDFLAGS ?